# Limits coincide distance tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$
$\newcommand{\max}{\operatorname{Max}}$

> Let $(X,d)$, $X \not= \emptyset$, a
> metric space and $(x_{n})_{n \in \N}$ and $(y_{n})_{n \in \N}$
> sequences in $X$. Show that if there exists a $a \in X$ such that:
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{n}} = a = \lim_{n \to \infty}{y_{n}}$$
> Then:
> $$\lim_{n \to  \infty}{d(x_{n},y_{n})} = 0$$
>
> Is the converse also true? (proof or counterexample).

Here is my attempt:

Suppose that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{x_{n}} = a = \lim_{n \to \infty}{y_{n}}$$

We want to see that:

$$\lim_{n \to  \infty}{d(x_{n},y_{n})} = 0$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, take $\varepsilon = \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ so in both cases there exists $N_{1},N_{2} > 0$ such that:

$$\forall_{n > N_{1}}\left[ d(x_{n},a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]$$

$$\forall_{n > N_{2}}\left[ d(y_{n},a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\right]$$

Now, set $N = \max{N_{1},N_{2}}$. Then, if we add both equations we have that:

$$\forall_{n > N} [d(x_{n},a) + d(y_{n},a) < \varepsilon]$$

Using the triangular inequality:

$$\forall_{n > N} [d(x_{n},y_{n}) < \varepsilon]$$

In particular:

$$\forall_{n > N} [|d(x_{n},y_{n}) - 0 |< \varepsilon ]$$

In fact we find that:

$$\forall_{\varepsilon}\{\exists_{N > 0} \{\forall_{n > N_{1}}[ |d(x_{n},y_{n}) - 0| <\varepsilon]\}\}$$

So by definitiuon of limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}{d(x_{n},y_{n})} = 0$$

What do you think?

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I am lost! I do not know what can I do. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Can you restate what $x_n \to a$ means in terms of $d(-,-)$?

Comment: Done! I could do it!

Comment: If you have an update, for example an attempt, you should edit the question, not post a new answer. I have added your attempt to the question body so that it is less likely people vote to close your question

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks! I am new and I do not completly the rules!!

Comment: They are more like strategies than rules.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Let $N_1 \in \Bbb N$ be such that

$$\forall n \ge N_1: d(x_n, a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\tag{1}$$

by $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n =a$ and $N_2 \in \Bbb N$ such that

$$\forall n \ge N_2: d(y_n, a) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}\tag{2}$$

by $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n =a$. Now set $N=\max(N_1,N_2)$ and use

$$\forall n: d(x_n,y_n) \le d(x_n,a) + d(y_n, a)$$

to finish showing that

$$\forall n \ge N: |d(x_n, y_n) - 0| < \varepsilon$$

as is required to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} d(x_n,y_n) =0$.

The converse need not hold. Let $X$ be the set $\Bbb Q$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ as usual, or even easier $X=\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ in that same metric.

Comment: I do not see wich sequences could work as counterexamples. I always feel that if their distances is becoming smaller as we go to infnity we have the  same limit

Comment: @GermánLópez In the last example $x_n = \frac1n$ and $y=-\frac1n$ work. Note that $0 \notin X$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part $d(x_n,y_n) \leq d(x_n,a)+d(a,y_n)$ can also be used.

The converse holds true only if one of the sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ is Cauchy and the  space $(X,d)$ is complete. Because: from
$d(x_n,x_m) \leq d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,y_m)+d(y_m,x_m)$ and $d(y_n,y_m) \leq d(y_n,x_n)+d(x_n,x_m)+d(x_m,y_m)$ we get $\lim_{n,m \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n, x_m)=\lim_{n,m \rightarrow \infty}d(y_n, y_m)$. So $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy iff $(y_n)_n$ is so. By completeness of $(X,d)$, $\exists~~~a,b \in X$ such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(x_n, a)=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}d(y_n, b)=0$. $d(a,b) \leq d(a,x_n)+d(x_n,y_n)+d(y_n,b)$, taking limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have $d(a,b)=0\Rightarrow a=b$.

Example that shows Cauchy condition can't be dropped: take $x_{2n-1}=2n-1$, $x_{2n}=\frac{1}{2n}$ and $y_{2n-1}=2n-1$, $y_{2n}=\frac{1}{n}$ in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$.
That the completeness condition can't be dropped can be seen from @Henno Brandsma's example

Comment: For an even easier counterexample: $x_n=y_n=n$.

Comment: Yes of course. I just wanted to take them different.